# Need a list of one level down from domain to be numbered to choice menu to select from to do next part?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, multiple-choice

I'm trying to reset passwords for my users, but controlled to do it one store at a time.
I'm using the command:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "store-*"' | FT Name, DistinguishedName -AutoSize
```

to show all the OU one level down, but I want to select from that list (1-20) the store I want to change.

This I will use the code to reset the password flag for that store only:

```
$days = 42  #change date here according to GPO.
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter { enabled -eq $true } -Properties pwdLastSet |
    Select-Object samaccountname, @{n = 'pwdLastSet'; e = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet) } } |
    Where-Object { $_.pwdlastset -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days) }

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $sam = $user.samaccountname

    $todouser = Get-ADUser $sam -Properties pwdLastSet, distinguishedname

    $todouser.pwdLastSet = 0
    Set-ADUser -Instance $todouser

    $todouser.pwdLastSet = -1
    Set-ADUser -Instance $todouser
}
```

---

I want all admins to be able to pick a store and do all users, then move on.  I just don't want to change all users in company in mass on the same day - wow what a disaster that would be.

I just can't find any code to take the output from the first line of code and make it into a choice list on screen.  Then take choice and use it to help select the filter in the second part.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest built-in method you can use in PowerShell to offer a selection is with [`OutGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.4), using [`-OutputMode Single`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.4#-outputmode) to ensure that the users can only pick a single Organizational Unit. You can add a condition later on to ensure that the user made a selection.

Then for the filtering of users, you can include `-SearchBase` and `-SearchScope` to target that specific Organizational Unit and to specify if you want to look for users one level in that hierarchy or recursive search. You can also use the Active Directory filter to find users which's password has not been set in the past 42 days.

Lastly, `Set-ADUser` already has the [`-ChangePasswordAtLogon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-changepasswordatlogon) flag, much easier than manually setting `pwdLastSet`.

```bash
$selection = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "store-*"' |
    Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName |
    Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title 'Pick an OrganizationalUnit'

if (-not $selection) {
    throw 'Please make a selection...'
}

$days = 42  # change date here according to GPO.
$targetDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).ToFileTimeUtc()

$getADUserSplat = @{
    Filter      = "enabled -eq '$true' -and pwdLastSet -lt '$targetDate'"
    SearchBase  = $selection.DistinguishedName # Setting base here
    SearchScope = 'OneLevel' # Change to 'Subtree' to target all users in that hierarchy
}

$updatedUsers = Get-ADUser @getADUserSplat |
    Set-ADUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -PassThru
```

Comment: Just change -Passthru to -OutputMode Single and they can only pick one item.

Comment: @DougMaurer thank you! wasnt aware of that parameter :P

Comment: I am quite shocked. I consider you one of the most knowledgeable powershell users I know. I bet you forgot more about powershell than most will ever even know. :)

Comment: Well thanks @DougMaurer appreciate the kind words tho I'm just an apprentice. I didn't know about that parameter cause I simply don't use `Out-GridView` lol

Comment: Indeed, `-PassThru` is the same as `-OutputMode Multiple` (just learned that myself). Interestingly, the console-based, cross-platform `Out-ConsoleGridView` (`Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools`) no longer supports `-PassThru`